# printf не работает как надо

Tags: java, printf

сдвигает на одно значение меньше чем указано в переменной

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numb = 1234;
        int arg = 1;
        int shift = 3;

        String shiftPrint = "%" + shift + "d";

        System.out.println(numb);
        System.out.printf(shiftPrint, arg);
    }

}
```

результат вывода:

```
1234
  2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внимательно прочитайте JavaDoc для `java.util.Formatter`. Согласно документации на `System.out.printf`, именно он регулирует правила выдачи.

А у него в документации написано следующее:

```
 * <p> The optional <i>width</i> is a positive decimal integer indicating
 * the minimum number of characters to be written to the output.
```

Вы передали число длиной 1 (единицу), а ему надо напечатать минимум 3 символа (вы ему задали такой параметр, 3). То есть он должен печатать вашу единицу и потом 2 пробела, вместе получается 3 символа от левого края. Именно это и видим в вашем эксперменте.

Переменную `shift`, наверное, нужно переименовать в `width`, чтобы называть вещи своими именами.

В этом же документе описан целиком формат:

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

Про каждый из этих модификаторов написано всё в том же JavaDoc.